# Visualforce page rendered PDF shows a strange error,

Tags: pdf

I am trying to view this visualforce as a PDF when it simply shows the page titled and remains blank.  The page displays fine when viewed in the browser but I have now created a second Custom Button to open up a 2nd Visualforce page that simply lets the user Save a copy of the PDF to related record.

The error simply looks like this; the "pdftest" is the name of the page:

[image: PDF Error page]

It only contains a few lines of text:

```
  <apex:page renderAs="pdf" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page: pdftest
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

I am using [Jeff Douglas's](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/14/attach-a-pdf-to-a-record-in-salesforce/) sample code here but with getContentAsPDF().

Comment: Remove the development mode toolbar by clicking on the X or whatever closes it on the right side of the bar. It can mess with things. Once removed refresh and see if it works.

Comment: Your absolutely right  - thanks (create an answer and i'll tick it).  I presume there is no workaround as the development mode has it's uses...

Comment: done............

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please mark as accepted so others looking for answers to a similar question can find questions with answers...

Answer (score 5):

Remove the development mode toolbar by clicking on the X or whatever closes it on the right side of the bar. It can mess with things